# @Autowired bean in Play! Framework

Tags: playframework, autowired

We know that if we use Spring framework we can use `@Autowired` bean for class and define in the applicationContext.xml

I want to do something like following:

> There are ManagerClasses which based on request will log the information in database.
>   This database will be used for activity monitoring(using MongoDB).
>
> The idea of using  @Autowired is that in an application Conntext I will get a singleton instance of the particular bean.
>
> If @Autowired is there, the ManagerClasses can wire up the bean DBPersist and log the information in database.

Please let me know if this could be done another way incase `@Autowired` is not in Play!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the Spring module for play?
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/spring

There is the @Inject annotation to inject a Spring bean into a controller.
Don't know if it helps...